# Is the $L^1$-norm of the FT of $(x+i)^n/(x-i)^{n+2}$ bounded as a sequence in $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, laguerre-polynomials

Let the function $f_n\in L^1(\mathbb R)\cap C_0(\mathbb R)$ be defined for $n\in\mathbb N$ by
$$f_n(x):=\left(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right)^n\frac{1}{(x-i)^2}\,.$$
Then its Fourier transform is always of the form
$$\hat{f_n}(x)=q_n(x)e^{-x}\theta(x)\,,$$
for a polynomial $q_n$ of degree at most $n+1$ and $\theta$ the Heaviside step function. As Jason pointed out in the comments, $q_n(x)=-\sqrt{2\pi}\int_0^x L_n(2t)dt$, with $L_n$ the $n$th Laguerre polynomial.

Clearly, $\|\hat{f_n}\|_1<\infty$. However, *is $\|\hat{f_n}\|_1$ bounded as a function in $n$?*

---

**Why I need this:**

I'm studying regularity properties of functions on $\mathbb R$ obtained via the Cayley transform from functions on the circle. I found out that the problem of integrability of the Fourier transform of a large class of functions can be reduced this very concrete question.

---

**What I've tried:**

I tried to use the general estimate $\|\hat{f_n}\|_1\leq c(\|f_n\|_2+\|f_n'\|_2)$, but unfortunately $\|f_n'\|_2$ blows up as $n\to\infty$. I thought about using complex analysis, like e.g. contour integration, but I am not very well versed in that subject.
I also used Wolframalpha to determine the polynomials $q_n$, and subsequently determining $\|\hat{f_n}\|_1$ for small $n$. I got (up to a possible factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$):

$\|\hat{f_0}\|_1=1$

$\|\hat{f_1}\|_1=1.20728$

$\|\hat{f_2}\|_1=1.37548$

$\|\hat{f_3}\|_1=1.52031$

$\|\hat{f_4}\|_1=1.64932$

before my Wolframalpha computation time was exceeded. It [looks](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%2C%201.20728%2C%201.37548%2C%201.52031%2C%201.64932) as though this sequence might stay below 2 (or some larger number) but I couldn't prove this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but it seems like the $q_n$ are closely related to the Laguerre polynomials. I think that, up to a constant factor, we have $q_n(x) = \int_0^x L_{n-1}(2t) \, dt$.

Comment: One other thought: I would expect resolving this to be fairly subtle. Here's an article that does a careful asymptotic analysis of certain $L^p$ norms of Laguerre polynomials themselves: https://www.keldysh.ru/papers/2015/prep2015_41_eng.pdf. Maybe some of the techniques and estimates there could be of use. My own hunch would be that the $L^1$ norms of the $\hat{f_n}$ are unbounded.

Comment: @Jason, those are very good comments, thank you! The problem is indeed very subtle. A first step might be to translate $\|\hat{f_n}\|_1$ to the $L^1$ norm of $\hat{L_n}$, possibly times some weight?

Comment: You're welcome! My thought was a little different, I think, although including the exponential weight is definitely important. I was imagining trying to derive a $q_n$-analogue of the Plancherel-Rotach asymptotics for Laguerre polynomials. I've been looking at some parts of Szegö's *Orthogonal Polynomials* (chapter 8 in particular) to see how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be coming late to the game at this point, but here's how we can work through the details to show that the $L^1$ norms of the $\hat{f_n}$ are unbounded. I won't get into a justification of the formula for the $q_n$ in terms of the Laguerre polynomials. And I want to note that I'm drawing heavily on Szegö's *Orthogonal Polynomials*, and will be mirroring the notation there quite a bit.

**Step 1: Converting to generalized Laguerre polynomials**

To begin, let's start with the formula for the Laguerre polynomails themselves: we have
$$
L_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}
\binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} x^k.
$$
Using the relationship $q_n(x) = -\sqrt{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{x} L_n(2t) \, dt$,
but dropping the constant factor of $-\sqrt{2 \pi}$ for simplicity, we get
$$
q_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}
\binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!} 2^k x^{k+1}.
$$
With a little extra algebra, we can express the $q_n$ in terms of the generalized Laguerre polynomials $L_n^{(\alpha)}$ as follows:
$$
q_n(x) = \frac{x}{n+1} L_n^{(1)}(2x).
$$

**Step 2: Asymptotics**

Now we can directly use the Plancherel-Rotach asymptotics for the $L_n^{(\alpha)}$ as developed in *Orthogonal Polynomials*. These asymptotics give an approximation for $L_n^{(\alpha)}(x)$ for $x_0 \leq x \leq (4 - \eta)n$, where we can think of $x_0$ and $\eta$ as fixed, small positive numbers. To re-state these asymptotics, we let $l_n = (4n + 4)^{1/2}$ and also introduce auxiliary variables $\xi$ and $\phi$, related to $x$ and to each other by the relationship $x = \xi^2 = l_n^2 \cos^2 \phi$. Then
\begin{align*}
e^{-x/2} L_n^{(1)}(x)
&= e^{-\xi^2 / 2} L_n^{(1)}(\xi^2) \\
&= (-1)^n (\pi \sin \phi)^{-1/2} \xi^{-3/2} n^{1/4} \\
& \qquad \times \left\{
\sin \left(
(n + 1)
(\sin 2 \phi - 2 \phi)
+ \frac{3 \pi}{4}
\right)
+ O(\xi^{-1} l_n^{-1}).
\right\}
\end{align*}
For the $q_n$, we therefore obtain
\begin{align*}
e^{-x/2} q_n(x/2)
&= \frac{x}{2n + 2} e^{-x/2} L_n^{(1)}(x) \\
&= 2 l_n^{-2} (-1)^n (\pi \sin \phi)^{-1/2} \xi^{1/2} n^{1/4} \\
& \qquad \times \left\{
\sin \left(
(n + 1)
(\sin 2 \phi - 2 \phi)
+ \frac{3 \pi}{4}
\right)
+ O(\xi^{-1} l_n^{-1})
\right\} \\
&= g_n(x/2) + R_n(x/2),
\end{align*}
where again $x = \xi^2 = l_n^2 \cos^2 \phi$ and the range of $x$-values where this holds is $x_0 \leq x \leq (4 - \eta) n$.

---

Now we turn to estimating
$$
\int_{x_0 / 2}^{(2 - \eta/2) n} | \hat{f_n}(y) | \, dy
= \frac{1}{2} \int_{x_0}^{(4 - \eta) n} | e^{-x/2} q_n(x/2) | \, dx
$$
from below.

**Step 3: The remainder term**

We begin with the remainder term $R_n$. Using $C$ to denote a constant that may vary from line to line but which is independent of $n$, we have via the change of variable $t = \cos \phi = \xi / l_n$:
\begin{align*}
I_R
&= \int_{x_0}^{(4 - \eta)n} | R_n(x/2) | \, dx \\
&\leq C l_n^{-3} n^{1/4}
\int_{x_0}^{(4 - \eta)n} (\sin \phi)^{-1/2} \xi^{-1/2} \, dx \\
&\leq C l_n^{-3} n^{1/4}
\int_0^1 (1 - t^2)^{-1/4} (l_n t)^{-1/2} \cdot 2 l_n^2 t \, dt \\
&= C l_n^{-3/2} n^{1/4}
\int_0^1 (1 - t^2)^{-1/4} t^{1/2} \, dt \\
&= C l_n^{-3/2} n^{1/4}.
\end{align*}
So $I_R = O(n^{-1/2})$.

**Step 4a: The main term - changes of variable**

The main term with $g_n$ is more involved. As a first step, we carry out a change of variable to $\phi$ in the integral:
\begin{align*}
I_g
&= \int_{x_0}^{(4 - \eta)n} | g_n(x/2) | \, dx \\
&= C l_n^{-2} n^{1/4} \int_{x_0}^{(4 - \eta)n}
(\sin \phi)^{-1/2} \xi^{1/2}
\left|
\sin \left(
(n + 1)
(\sin 2 \phi - 2 \phi)
+ \frac{3 \pi}{4}
\right)
\right|
\, dx \\
&= C l_n^{1/2} n^{1/4} \int_{a_n}^{b_n}
(\sin \phi)^{1/2} (\cos \phi)^{3/2}
\left|
\sin \left(
(n + 1)
(\sin 2 \phi - 2 \phi)
+ \frac{3 \pi}{4}
\right)
\right|
\, d\phi,
\end{align*}
where $a_n = \cos^{-1} (\sqrt{(4 - \eta)n}/l_n)$ and $b_n = \cos^{-1} (\sqrt{x_0}/l_n)$. Note that as $n \to \infty$, we have $a_n \to \cos^{-1} (\sqrt{1 - \eta/4})$ and $b_n \to \pi / 2$.

We can additionally change variable via $s = \sin 2 \phi - 2 \phi$; this transformation doesn't permit an entirely closed-form expression for the new integrand, but we can still write
$$
I_g
= C l_n^{1/2} n^{1/4} \int_{c_n}^{d_n}
\tilde{g}(s)
\left|
\sin \left(
(n + 1) s
+ \frac{3 \pi}{4}
\right)
\right|
\, ds
$$
for an appropriate function $\tilde{g}$ and numbers $c_n$ and $d_n$, where $c_n \to -\pi$ and $d_n \to d = \sqrt{\eta (1 - \eta/4)} - 2 \cos^{-1} (\sqrt{1 - \eta/4}) < 0$.

**Step 4b: The main term - Féjer's lemma**

We can now apply Fejér's lemma to understand the limiting behavior of the remaining integral. This lemma states that if $h_1 \in L^1([0, \pi])$, and if $h_2 \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is $\pi$-periodic, then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} h_1(s) h_2(ns) \, ds
= \left(
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} h_2(x) \, ds
\right)
\left(
\int_{0}^{\pi} h_1(s) \, ds
\right).
$$
A straightforward corollary is that if $h_1^{(n)} \to h_1$ in $L^1([0, \pi])$, then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} h_1^{(n)}(s) h_2(ns) \, ds
= \left(
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} h_2(s) \, ds
\right)
\left(
\int_{0}^{\pi} h_1(s) \, ds
\right).
$$

In our problem, the role of $h_2$ is taken by $| \sin (\cdot + 3\pi / 4) |$, and
$$
h_1^{(n)}
= \chi_{[c_n, d_n]} \tilde{g}
\to \chi_{[-\pi, d]} \tilde{g}
= h_1.
$$
We can therefore conclude that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}
&\int_{c_n}^{d_n}
\tilde{g}(s)
\left|
\sin \left(
(n + 1) s
+ \frac{3 \pi}{4}
\right)
\right|
\, ds \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}
\int_{-\pi}^{d} \tilde{g}(s) \, ds \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}
\int_{\cos^{-1} (\sqrt{1 - \eta/4})}^{\pi / 2}
(\sin \phi)^{1/2} (\cos \phi)^{3/2}
\, d\phi \\
&> 0.
\end{align*}

So concluding with the main term, we can say that $I_g \geq C n^{1/2}$ for sufficiently large $n$, where $C > 0$ does not depend on $n$.

---

The lower bound for $I_g$ and the upper bound for $I_R$ now imply that the norms $\| \hat{f_n} \|_{1}$ are unbounded.

Comment: Wow. Amazing work! I'll try to check everything. You used Theorem 8.22.8(a), right? Am I correct in assuming that $O(\xi^{-1}l_n^{-1})$ is meant uniformly in $x=\xi^2\in[x_0,(4-\eta)n]$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: That's exactly right about which theorem I was relying on. Also, I realize now that I used slightly different notation for the asymptotics, from equation 8.73.18. And yes, my understanding of the $O(\xi^{-1} l_n^{-1})$ is that it's uniform in precisely the way you say. Szegö doesn't seem to be super-precise on this point in his statement of the results, and I haven't gone through the proofs in detail to verify, but I would be very surprised if the uniformity wasn't in both $x$ and $n$.